# css properties - are they all same?

Tags: css, colors, web, background, background-color

what is the difference in each line of following footer property?

isn't they all same? if so, why declare multiple times?

```css
#footer {   
    background: #1b1b1b;
    color: #5b5b5a;
    background-color: #cccccc;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: What makes you think they're all the same?

Comment: background-color is a part of background. you can choose anything from both. color is for coloring the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`color` sets the text color. 
`background-color` sets the background color. 
`background` is shorthand for a number of other properties, for example: `background: url("topbanner.png") #00D repeat-y fixed;`

Answer (score 1):

`color` is for the color of the text.
`background-color` defines the color of the background behind the text. 
`background` is just a shortcut that allows you to declare color+image+other properties at the same time (instead of using `background-color`, then `background-image`, etc.). 
So here, the only redundant lines are `background` and `background-color`. `background-color` is actually overriding `background` in your example, so your footer will have a light grey (ccc) background, with a darker grey text.